# Yii2 pjax reload

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I am trying to submit the form via pjax and after submission I want to refresh the table but after submitting the form and trying to reload ( `$.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});` ) the jquery scripts are not working anymore. Even I added `pjax:success` but if I don't reload the table, all scripts are working and sending the requests and then I have to reload manually in order to see the changes. Or I have tried to submit form without pjax and the page reloads by Yii and then again proplems with scripts. Please your feedbacks. Thanks

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
    $("form.products-input-style").on('beforeSubmit', function(e){

            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success  : function(response) {
                    $.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});
                    $.notify({
                        icon: "pe-7s-check",
                        message: "Product is updated."

                    },{
                        type: type[2],
                        timer: 10,
                        placement: {
                            from: 'top',
                            align: 'right'
                        }
                    });
                },
                error : function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $.notify({
                        icon: "pe-7s-close-circle",
                        message: "Error! " + response

                    },{
                        type: type[4],
                        timer: 10,
                        placement: {
                            from: 'top',
                            align: 'right'
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;

        }).on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have problem with input forms after pjax reload then, try to disable yii client side validation:

```
ActiveForm::begin([
  'enableClientScript' => false,
]);
```

This is some bug on yii\widgets\ActiveForm and yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm.

Answer (score 0):

I think your handler will replaced by new html code (after Pjax update). 
Try to use [delegated handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

For example:

```js
$(function(){

    $(document).on('beforeSubmit', 'form.products-input-style', function(event){
        // ...
    }

});
```